# How should I include pension contributions in my UK Child Benefit calculations?

Tags: united-kingdom, calculation, pension, children, benefits

I'm using the gov.uk [Child Benefit Tax Calculator](https://www.gov.uk/child-benefit-tax-calculator/main) and I don't know how I include my pension contributions in the "Pension contributions deducted from your pay" and "Pension contributions not paid from your salary" fields.

I contribute 5% from salary and my employer 10%. What do I need to include, and should it be before or after tax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under "Pension contributions deducted from your pay" you need to put in the £ amount of the 5% that you pay from your salary. If your gross salary is £50k then you would put £2500 in that field.

Under "Pension contributions not paid from your salary" you need to put in any additional amounts that you have paid into any pensions, eg by sending in a cheque or making a Direct Debit or Standing Order. This may well be £0 in your specific case.

You do not need to enter the 10% employer contribution anywhere.